# Calling native ios function from a webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I am having a requirement to invoke a ios native function when a particular page in a webview is accessed. I have seen some solutions of using a javascript bridging mechanism using which you can invoke but this is not possible in my case as changes to website are ruled out.Need some suggestions for solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: what's your problem ?

Comment: Inject your JS to webview's page (it's possible on client side) and call what you need using this "javascript bridging mechanism"

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the delegate method of a `UIWebView`, see below

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSString *url = request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"Url = %@",url);

    if([url isEqualToString:@"YOUR_URL"]){
        //Do Something

        return NO;
    }


    return YES;
}
```

See if it helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look the [XWebView](http://github.com/XWebView/XWebView) project if you are using WKWebView.